# when viewport is smaller then 480, the source of the image change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm doing a header for my site with an image. The height and width of this image is = 100vw and 100vh respectively. The problem is when viewport is, per example, 480px, the image gets deformed.

I tried to solve the problem creating a new image with proportions i want and doing this with bootstrap:

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #imgTOPO::after {
        content:url("/assets/head_480-01.png");
    }
}
```

But the image isn't changing and i can't figure the problem. What can i do to solve this?

Comment: try removing ::after, use selector only `#imgTOPO {
        content:url("/assets/head_480-01.png");
    }`

Comment: @Omi the `content` property *only* works with pseudo selectors, so your code will not work.

Comment: If an answer solved your question, mark it as accepted. If you found a solution yourself, write an answer yourself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problrem is the `height` value, both width and height of the img are set to fill the viewport, to mantain the aspect ratio remove the `height = 100vh` or set to `height = auto`.

```css
img {
    width: 100vw;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
```

It solves the problem of deformation, but if you still want to load different images for each resolution for responsiveness sake you can take a look to `srcset` https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/

Answer (score 1):

This is one possible solution.

**HTML:**

```
<img src="someImg.png" class="largeImg" />
<img src="someImg.png" class="smallImg" />
```

**CSS:**

```
 .largeImg {
    display:block;
  }

  .smallImg {
    display: none;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
   .largeImg {
      display: none;
   }

   .smallImg {
     display: block;
   }
  }
```

I hope that helps!:) @Mariana